# The document has no pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have problem in gridview export to the pdf use iTextsharp ASP.NET .

The error says : The document has no pages, in pdfdoc.close();

this is my code :

```
protected void btnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=ProduktivitasReport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End(); 
}
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: You're creating document but aren't adding anything.

Comment: @khlr Im adding Gridview into document.

Comment: This is because your grid contains some script which may not be readable by itextsharp. So try with a simple code htmlparser.Parse(new StringReader("hello world")); and check its working fine.

Comment: Oh Thanks. My problem is fixed.